# Best way to simply store data for statistical analysis in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have been using text files to store my data for R without any problem for some time now. But for a recent project the files' sizes are getting too big for raw text files to handle. What's the best simple alternative?

Comment: In what way are text files becoming too big? Are you afraid for their integrity? Not able to open them in some other software? Are they too slow to load? Too big for your hard drive (laptop?)?

Comment: +1 Managing data as projects grow is a universal issue in data analysis (and is hardly specific to `R`). The fundamental concern is with data integrity rather than file size: proposing some form of compression merely obscures this rather than solving it.

Comment: Above a certain size txt just doesn't seem to work.  I can add the extra data to the txt file and load it into R, but the extra data isn't in R.  (Btw the data is pretty rich so while compression may help a bit it wouldn't get me that far and I suspect as my project grows I'll end up with the same issues again.)

Comment: You need to tell us more about your data, there is no such thing as "best way to any sort of data".

Comment: Do you mean that `read.table` or `read.csv` are failing silently? Are you absolutely sure you don't have several files lying around and some coding error (wrong path, wrong file name, etc.)? Just to fix ideas, you might also want to give us an idea of how many variables and how many records you are approximately dealing with.

Comment: I suggest this question be migrated to StackOverflow, as it is clearly a programming issue rather than a statistics-related one.

Answer (score 10):

The standard R approach is to use `save` and `load`.  If you run `save` on your data frame after importing and annotating it, you can specify `compress=TRUE` and you'll be amazed at the compression and the fast `load` time.  This works especially well if the object size is less than about 400MB.  Otherwise, check out some of the suggestions above, or the powerful `ff` package in R.

The `Hmisc` package has little wrappers `Save` and `Load` to make the above even more painless:

```
mydata <- csv.get(...)  # Hmisc package, has several options
Save(mydata)   # writes mydata.rda to current working directory
....
Load(mydata)   # reads mydata.rda and creates mydata data frame
```

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at SQLite3 databases. Each database is a file, so it doesn't require setting up a database server.

To create a database:

```
$ sqlite3 my_db.db3
> CREATE TABLE my_table ( col1 TEXT );
```

For use with R, https://gist.github.com/lynaghk/1062939

Comment: +1 Using an actual database is a huge step in the right direction.

Comment: Would this be the appropriate tool? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try this route.  I looked at MySQL too, but seems to be more than I need.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of generic options.

- You could compress the text.
- You could go binary on the text, not write in ascii

Great compression is data dependent.

My guess (and you didn't specify so I must guess) is that you are looking to store spreadsheet-like data in something other than csv (comma-delimited).

One of my favorite formats (I love MatLab) is hdf.

Here is R-related information about HDF:

- accessed through packages hdf5, h5r, Bioconductor's rhdf5, RNetCDF, ncdf and ncdf4
- http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/whatishdf5.html

It is a high-density supercomputing data storage format.  It can be very fast and efficient.  It is also (unsurprisingly) denser than zipped text.

Answer (score 3):

Standard file reading functions in R will now automatically easily read gzipped files. So, just run simple gzip compression on your data and read as always, as if it was plain text.

```
read.table('myfile.gz')
```

Comment: Neat!  I did not know that.  Thank you.